# Why do siddurim and Shulchan Oruch OC start with Shacharis?

Tags: prayer-book, time, shulchan-aruch, mishna

Why do [siddurim](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/sidurim/ashkenaz/hol/shaharit.asp#1) and [Shulchan Oruch OC](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14170&st=&pgnum=6&hilite=) start with the morning? Since the day starts with night, they should start with Maariv as does the [mishnah](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%90).

Comment: usually sidurim starts with mode ani, and not shaharit, but the question is still valid

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps or hurts your case, but a number of _machzorim_ I have seen over the years begin with _mincha_.

Comment: I noticed that in my siddur, Shabbat Maariv davening is listed before Shabbat Shacharit.

Comment: ([Shu"t Tzapichas Bidvash](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=501&st=&pgnum=9&hilite=) addresses this question)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We say every morning "Neshalma parim sefatenu". 
Since we cannot offer Korbanot , we got the Tfila instead. 
So the Tfila follows the order of the Korbanot.
For the Korbanot the day starts after sunrise.

Answer (score 14):

In [the introduction to the Tur](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14265&pgnum=4) (upon which the Shulchan Aruch is based), R' Yaakov Baal HaTurim writes that he organized the Sefer based on the order of the day, how a person should conduct himself from when he wakes up until he goes to sleep.

Comment: The more so, since when you wake up in the morning you're a new person, with your soul having been returned to you (for which we say Modeh Ani and Elokai Neshamah).

Comment: the questions still stands, why is this considered the order of the day, since the day actually starts at night, the actual order is arvit first

Comment: I think it answers the question.  The Shulchan Aruch is not concerned with halachic order, but in a "set table" of practices for a Jew to serve G-d.  It would make sense to start the instructions from when a person awakens and continue until he turns in at night.

Comment: Indeed, siddurs that contain Tikkun Chatzos start with that, even though it is said at night, specifically because it is the first thing one says on waking.

Comment: @yoel: not all of them do. The siddur of R. Shneur Zalman of Liadi places tikkun chatzos after kerias shema she'al hamittah, and in his notes on that siddur, Dayan Raskin [cites](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=30450&pgnum=431) a talk by R. Yosef Yitzchak Schneersohn, that this is because the latter is really the beginning of and basis for the avodah of tikkun chatzos.

Comment: @Alex huh, interesting!  Why isn't Tikkun Chatzos in the regular Chabad siddur?  Do any (or rather, do any significant number of) Lubavitchers say it?

Comment: @yoel: it's in the thick Tehillas Hashem siddur too. It is true, though, that saying it has become pretty rare among Chabad chassidim.

Comment: @Alex  I know that many chasidim regard it as something for tzadikim only, although in Breslev we are particular to say it as Rebbe Nachman speaks very highly of the practice.  Have the past rebbes in Chabad had anything to say on the matter?  I assume they themselves did say it regardless...

Comment: @yoel: there are some sources on the subject cited on the next page after the one I linked above. So far as I know, all of the Chabad rebbeim did say tikkun chatzos, but it seems from the sources cited there that they said that the average person doesn't require it every night (and there is a citation there where the Rebbe said that the study of Chassidus after midnight accomplishes the same thing as tikkun chatzos).

Answer (score 2):

Avraham initiated Shacharis, Yitzchok initiated Mincha, Yaakov initiated Maariv. **The order of the Siddurim is in the order they were initiated.** In addition Shacharis is considered the main Tefila of the day. Also practically Mincha / Maariv are often said immediately one after the other.

Comment: A source for the idea that shachrit is the main tefillah of the day can be found in Derech Hashem 4:6:16. I won't quote it here since it's rather esoteric.

Comment: The word "composed" is wrong here.  The tefilot were composed by the Anshei Kneset, as well as many other factors that created the siddur as we have it today. You should stick with "initiated"